# vb.net get line number of find words in richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

is there any way  to get line number of highlighted words in richtextbox  here is the code of highlighting text in richtextbox

for example

```
  i am  *doing code for *practice 
  this is very hard *language 
  its very *good day
```

words with (*) marks are denoting highlighted words

i am trying to get out put

line no. 1  :  doing 
 line no. 1  :  practice 
 Line no. 2  :  language 
 line no. 3  :  good

here is my code to highlight the words in richtextbox

```
Dim len As Integer = txtMbox.TextLength
    For Each word As String In MisSpelledList

        Dim lastindex = txtMbox.Text.LastIndexOf(word)
        Dim index As Integer = 0

        While index < lastindex

            txtMbox.Find(word, index, len, RichTextBoxFinds.None)

            txtMbox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red


            index = txtMbox.Text.IndexOf(word, index) + 1


        End While
```

Comment: Will the user be putting in the '*'?

Comment: actully i used * mark to show highlighted words in this question. in real program words are highlighted with red background

Comment: You could make a statement for every swear word, and make a boolean that become true when the word is typed. Passing it all through an if statement.

Comment: You can do it in a couple of ways, in the part where you set the `BackColor` of the word, store the location(index) and optionally the word in a `Array` or `List` etc, then when you need the line number use `YourRichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)`